# How to integrate tinyMce editor in java web application

Tags: java, tinymce-4

My website largely depends on user input. I am using jsp and html as view technology. I am not able to integrate tinymce 4.3.8 editor with my web pages. On clicking submit it sends null value to servlet. Perhaps I did not configure it properly. All solutions I've found on Stackoverflow are not working for me. I tried other editors like nicEdit and Wmd Master also but the problem persists. Can anyone suggest a working solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After lot of googling I found the answer to this question. First we have to unzip the zip file. Then we have to include these two javascript files in our web page like this :-

```
<script src="tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Then we have to initialize the tinymce editor like this :-

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({
        selector : "textarea",

    });
</script>
```

and at last we have to define a text area in our page :-

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="TextServlet" method="post">
                    <h1>Type your text here</h1><br/>
                    <textarea id="text" rows="1" cols="10" name="qa" form="form">Enter text here...</textarea>
                    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

It is all done.